# convert time to to 12 hour by manipulate string

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time

```
"2015-06-23 14:00:00"
```

I tried to format above date time into 12 hour base but stuck in somewhere.

```
function formatDate(raw_date){
    var right = raw_date.substring(10, 0);

    var hours = ((right[0].substring(2,0) + 11) % 12 + 1);
    var min = raw_date.substring(14,16);
    var suffix = right[1] >= 12 ? "PM":"AM";
    right[1] = ((right[1] + 11) % 12 + 1) + suffix;
    return hours + ':' + min + ' ' + suffix;
}
```

Can someone help? My desired output is `"23/06/2015 02:00 PM"`

Comment: `var right = raw_date.substring(10, 0);`?! If `raw_date` is `"2015-06-23 14:00:00"` then `right` will be `"2015-06-23"`. And then `right[0].substring(2,0)`?!

Comment: I must say really don't understand your logic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on your code:

```
function formatDate(raw_date){
    var year = raw_date.substring(0,4);
    var month = raw_date.substring(5,7);
    var day = raw_date.substring(8,10); 
    var right = raw_date.substring(10);
    var hours = ((right.substring(0,3))% 12 );
    var min = raw_date.substring(14,16);
    var suffix = right.substring(0,3) >= 12 ? "PM":"AM";
    return day + "/"+month+"/"+year+" "+hours + ':' + min + ' ' + suffix;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function formatDate(raw_date) {
    var right = new Date(raw_date);

    var currentHours = right.getHours();
    var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
    if (currentHours > 12) {
        currentHours -= 12;
    }
    return (right.getDate() + '/' + right.getMonth()+ '/' + right.getFullYear() +" "+ currentHours+ ":"+right.getMinutes() + timeOfDay);
}

alert(formatDate("2015-06-23 14:00:00"));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/edv7aaax/)

Comment: Doesn't work at all in IE11 and Firefox 38.0.5. The output is NaN/NaN/NaN NaNPM

Answer (score 0):

You should follow a simple flow.
Try to break down the input ->  convert them _> and then sum them up:

```
function formatDate(raw_date){
    var right = raw_date.substring(0, 10);

    var year=right.substring(0,4);
    var month=right.substring(5,7);
    var day=right.substring(8,10);

    right=day+"/"+month+"/"+year;

    var left=raw_date.substring(11, raw_date.length);

    var hours = left.substring(0,2);
    var suffix = hours >= 12 ? "PM":"AM";
    hours=hours-12;
    if(hours<10) hours='0'+hours;

    var min = left.substring(3,5);

    left=hours+":"+min+" "+suffix;

    return right + ' ' + left;

}
```